# Программа Nuxt.js в Использует все ресурсы в Linux

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nuxt.js

У меня есть сайт, созданный на nuxt.js, я использую ssh-скрипт для обновления сайта и pm2 в качестве диспетчера процессов. Все работает нормально, но когда у сайта относительно высокий трафик, он падает. Администрация сервера пояснила, что существующее приложение использует все ресурсы сервера, ОЗУ на сервере составляет около 36 ГБ. На момент запуска все приложение использует 3,4 ГБ ОЗУ. Я прочитал много ресурсов, но не смог найти правильный источник, может все это быть вызвано узлом-модулем? Любые подсказки мне помогут, заранее большое спасибо

```js
//ecosystem.config.js

module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: 'NuxtAppName',
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        instances: 'max', // Or a number of instances
        script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
        args: 'start'
    }]
}
```

```js
//package.json

{
    "name": "devcomn",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
        "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0",
        "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
        "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.3.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "core-js": "^3.9.1",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
        "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
        "nuxt-facebook-pixel-module": "^1.5.0",
        "nuxt-lazy-load": "^1.2.6",
        "nuxt-moment": "^1.0.5",
        "swiper": "^5.4.5",
        "v-mask": "^2.2.4",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.11",
        "vue-authenticate": "^1.5.0",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
        "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
        "vue-google-oauth2": "^1.5.8",
        "vue-lazy-hydration": "*",
        "vue-select": "^3.11.2",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.2.13",
        "vue-star-rating": "^1.7.0",
        "vue2-dropzone": "^3.6.0",
        "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.4.0",
        "fibers": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
    }
}
```

```js
nuxt.config.js
const axios = require('axios')
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'site',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [

    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [ '~/assets/css/transition.css', '~/assets/css/errors.css' ],
  pageTransition: "fade",
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/axios' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-fbauth.js', ssr: false },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-google', ssr: false },
    { src: "~/plugins/star-rating", ssr: false },
    { src: "~/plugins/mask", ssr: false },
    { src: "~/plugins/rangeSlider", ssr: false },
    { src: "~/plugins/vueSelect", ssr: false },
    { src: "~/plugins/vuelidate", ssr: false },
  ],


  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    [ '@nuxtjs/google-analytics', {
      id: ''
    } ]
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/toast',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    [ 'nuxt-lazy-load', {
      defaultImage: '/spin2.gif'
    } ],
    [ 'nuxt-facebook-pixel-module', {
      /* module options */
      track: 'PageView',
      pixelId: '',
      autoPageView: true,
      disabled: false
    } ],
    'nuxt-moment',
    '@nuxt/http',
    '@nuxtjs/robots',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
  ],

  moment: {
    locales: ['ka', 'en']
  },


  toast: {
    position: 'top-center',
},

  robots: [
    {
      UserAgent: '*',
      Disallow: ['/user', '/admin'],
    },
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://api.site.com/', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
  },

  sitemap:{
     exclude:[
       '/user',
       '/admin',
       '/admin/*',
       '/user/*',
     ],
     defaults: {
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: new Date()
    },
     routes: async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.site.com/api/book/all')
      return data.map((product) => `https://site/product/${product.id}/${product.name}`)
    }
  },

  loading: {
    color: '#F48245',
    height: '4px'
  },

  target: 'server',

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},

  router: { middleware: [ 'checkUserAuth' ] },


};
```

Comment: Выставлять свойство `max_memory_restart: 'xxxM',` (или G для лигабайт) в файл экосистемы PM2 не пробовали? Ну и количество кластеров на max у Вас, само собой сколько есть ресурсов, столько и запускает. Ограничивайте числом.

Comment: Hi, `module.exports = {apps: [{name: 'NuxtAppName' , exec_mode: 'cluster', instances: 'max',script:'./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',args: 'start',max_memory_restart: "500M"}]}` это правильный синтаксис для pm2?

Comment: Да, лоличество кластеров (instances) ограничьте и тестируйте

Comment: И мог ли node_module вызвать перезагрузку системы?

Comment: большое спасибо, я попробую это решение